# Invalid Middleware found in Next.JS-13 (App routing)

Tags: typescript, mongodb, next.js13

This is code inside the middleware file:

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import type { NextRequest } from "next/server";

// This function can be marked `async` if using `await` inside
export function middleware(request :    NextRequest) {
    const path = request.nextUrl.pathname;
    const isPublicPath = path === '/login' || path === '/signup';
    const token = request.cookies.get('token')?.value || '';
    if (isPublicPath && token) {
        return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/', request.nextUrl));
    }
    if (!isPublicPath && !token) {
        return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/login', request.nextUrl));
    }
}

// See "Matching Paths" below to learn more
export const config = {
    matcher: ['/','/profile', 'login', '/signup'],
};
```

error is

`source` does not start with / for route {"source":"login"}

Error: Invalid middleware found

Any Solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/middleware#matcher) clearly specifies matcher paths MUST (it's actually written in uppercase in the docs) start with `/`:

> Configured matchers:
>
> 1. MUST start with /

So just add that missing `/`:

```
export const config = {
    matcher: ['/','/profile', '/login', '/signup'],
                              ☝️ HERE
};
```